# Objective-c subclassing gives linking error

Tags: objective-c, initialization, subclass

I'm trying to port a game to iOS but I'm having a problem. I have a class called CKSprite with the following method:

```
- (id)initWithFile:(NSString *)fileName effect:(GLKBaseEffect *)effect 
{     
    if ((self = [super init])) 
    {
        //some stuff
    }
    return self;
}
```

I then have a subclass called CKPLayer (it has no other methods or properties at the moment other than what it inherits:

```
@property (strong) CKPlayer *player1;
```

But when I try to initialise it using the parent method:

```
self.player1 = [[CKPlayer alloc] initWithFile:@"Images/parrot.png" effect:self.effect];
```

I get this error:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CKPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CKViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This is my first time trying to do anything like this so I've probably done something stupid.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#import "CKSprite.h"

@interface CKPlayer : CKSprite


@end
```

Comment: Does the `CKSprite` class eventually inherit from `NSObject`?

Comment: write CKPlayer class interface declaration in above question, that may help us to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker is missing the implementation for the class CKPlayer. Maybe you just forgot to implement it since it has "no other methods or properties at the moment", in that case just add a file which should look like:

```
#import "CKPlayer.h"

@implementation CKPlayer
@end
```

and ld should be happy

Comment: I already have a file that looks like that (and just in case I made a mistake I tried copying and pasting what you wrote as well but to no avail).

Comment: Well, either the compiler is not generating the correct symbols or it is not linked (is the file included in the target? is it compiled with the same arch i386 as the rest of the project?)

Comment: You've got it! The file was included under 'Compile sources) for some reason (I'm not sure why). Thanks a lot :D